# How to suppress execution of statement in script called with execfile?

Tags: python, unit-testing

The question as posed in the title may be a case of [the XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but I was unable to find a better concise description. I want to test a number of python scripts by running `execfile(filename)` on each of them, and then see whether they trigger an assertion/throw an exception. So far so good, but most of them also start a gui for conformation with one statement, lets say `world.show('someString')`. For automated testing, I don't want to see the gui. How can I suppress the gui without changing the scripts themselves?

**Edit:**
Regarding the comments: In essences, I could just do:

```
import unittest

class TestExamples(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_firstExample(self):
        execfile('example1.py')

    def test_secondExample(self):
        execfile('example2.py')

    # and many more

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But a) there are more than two, and I would prefer not to write a test function for each example. I would like them to be tested just by being in the folder. This could possibly be solved by unittests `discover`. And b), most of them end by visualising the calculation, just like you would with `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`. I want to suppress this visualisation, without changing the examples themselves.

Comment: You'd have to replace the GUI call with a mock, but if that is possible depends on the exact GUI. Still, I'd refactor the scripts to use a `main()` function instead.

Comment: What is it that Python's unittest module or "nose" can't do for you? That said, Martijn made a good point that you need to mock certain interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple option: assuming you have a file `world.py` like this...

```
def show(text):
    return some_gui_stuff.confirm(text)
```

...then create a new file `fakeworld.py` which looks like this...

```
def show(text):
    return True
```

...then in your test script, do something like...

```
import sys
sys.modules['world'] = __import__('fakeworld')
execfile('example1.py')
```

When `example1.py` tries to `import world`, it'll use the fake version you imported at the top of the test script.

This does mean you'll have to create a fake version for every function in `world.py`. If there's a lot of functions, but only one or two need changing, it might be easier to make the test script like this...

```
import world
import fakeworld
world.show = fakeworld.show
execfile('example1.py')
```

...or if `world.show` is literally the only function, you probably don't even need to create a `fakeworld.py` - just do something like...

```
import world
world.show = lambda x: True
execfile('example1.py')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the correct way would be to mock GUI you are using (as mentioned in comments below your question).

But the "easy way" might be to install [xvfb](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) -  virtual framebuffer X server (e.g for Debian it would be [xfvb](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/xvfb) package) and run your unittest script using following command:

```
xvfb-run python unittest.py
```

Comment: How would I go about "mocking" the GUI? `xvfb` aborts with GLX not found.

Comment: Well, this is just a configuration issue of your system, probably missing libgl-*-glx or sth like that (depending on driver you're using), but how to do fix that is a question to superuser or askubuntu site.